# Cannot redeclare class AGI_AsteriskManager

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

We downloaded latest phpagi 2.2. But when we are excuting our php file we are getting this error.

```
Cannot redeclare class AGI_AsteriskManager in /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/phpagi-asmanager.php on line 867
```

Here is our php file code

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
 //set_time_limit(30);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 require('phpagi.php');


 $agi = new AGI();
 // $agi->answer();
 $agi->say_number("1234"); // speaks the number 1234 
 $agi->say_digits("1234"); // speaks the digits 1, 2, 3 and 4. 
 //$cid = $agi->parse_callerid();
 $agi->text2wav("Hello");
 $agi->text2wav('Goodbye');
 // $agi->hangup();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change require('phpagi.php') to require_once ('phpagi.php')

Comment: i did, But not working. 
I removed all the content of phpagi-asmanager.php. And its working fine now. Dont know why this is happening

Comment: Indeed - first 10 lines, constructor (if class) and code from the error section

Comment: and of course, phpagi.php - 10 first lines would be nice to view. It seems like there are multiple class declarations somewhere. I suggest to remove any requirements from classes itself and make require_once directly in your agi executable

Answer (score 0):

Give complete path for phpagi.php file if its not in agi-bin folder

```
require_once "/path/to/phpagi.php";
```

And also make sure that `phpagi-asmanager.php` is in same folder where your `phpagi.php` is placed.